# django fabric syncdb

Tags: django, fabric

How would you  run this django command to syncdb  with fabric automatically.

```
python manage.py syncdb  --settings="app.settings.test"
```

if tried to do run, it gets stuck at the "Do you want to create superuser account", can it passed as yes and login information with it.

```
run('python manage.py syncdb  --settings="app.settings.%s"' % name, pty=True)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `--noinput` to the arguments to keep django-admin from prompting:

```
python manage.py syncdb --settings="app.settings.%s" --noinput
```

If you have specific credentials that you'd like to preload always, I suspect the simplest way to achieve that would be to create a data dump of the user database from a machine with (just!) the admin account loaded, and then to load that in after syncdb.  Alternatively, you could simply leave out the admin account and add it later with `manage.py createsuperuser` when and if you need to have it.

Comment: Or you can create a fixture with that data: then syncdb will add that when it creates the tables.

Comment: To clarify @MatthewSchinckel above - the fixture should be named 'initial_data.[xml/yaml/json]'