# using bash to automate answering of prompts for django sync for graphite install

Tags: bash, ubuntu, chef-infra

I am using chef to automate the install of graphite on ubuntu.  I need to automate the python manage.py syncdb using bash or by any other means.

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx:/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite$ sudo python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table account_profile
Creating table account_variable
Creating table account_view
Creating table account_window
Creating table account_mygraph
Creating table dashboard_dashboard_owners
Creating table dashboard_dashboard
Creating table events_event
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table tagging_tag
Creating table tagging_taggeditem

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (Leave blank to use 'root'): admin
E-mail address: test@gmail.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
No fixtures found.
```

I need to automate the following prompts with the below

```
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (Leave blank to use 'root'): admin
E-mail address: test@gmail.com
Password: test101
Password (again): test101
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).  I've never used it with anything other than sftp, but it should work with any interactive application.

Comment: Thanks...even better they have a pexpect for python:)

Answer (score 3):

Since I had the same issue and solved it using expect I figured I could share the expect script that I wrote:

```
set timeout -1
set program [ lindex $argv 0 ]
eval spawn $program [ lrange $argv 1 end ]
expect {
    "Would you like to create one now" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect "Username"
            send "admin\r"
            expect "E-mail"
            send "test@gmail.com\r"
            expect "Password"
            send "admin\r"
            expect "Password"
            send "admin\r"
            exp_continue
     } "Migrated" {
            expect eof
     }
}
```

Remember to customize the defaults admin and password.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to solve the "input" problem and want to automate the admin creation using fabric, consider pass the `--noinput` flag to **syncdb** and that **load a fixture** with user data already created.

Take a look here: [django fabric syncdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331750/django-fabric-syncdb)

Answer (score 0):

Would simply piping the data as stdin to the process work?

```
printf "%s\n" yes admin test@example.com test101 test101 | sudo python ...
```

or

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "%s\n" yes admin test@example.com test101 test101 | python ...'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this, but I wanted to say **no** instead of **yes**. So here is a minimal expect script based on unicoletti's example.

```
set timeout -1                                                                                                                                                          
spawn "./your_django_script.sh"                                                                                                                                     
expect {                                                                                                                                                                
    "Would you like to create one now" {                                                                                                                                
            send "no\r"                                                                                                                                                 
            exp_continue                                                                                                                                                
     }                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```